# In BIP RTF template table last row is not appearing as per requirement

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I have a BIP template on which I am generating table based on data from database. The table rows are doubled lined. The problem is that the last line is also appearing as doubled line:

[image]

but the requirement is that the last line should be a single line as shown in below image:

[image]

These are my rtf template and sample xml file for someone who can look into it.

[Sample XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khai75r0i75oozx/BIP%20ROH%20DCC%20Claim%20Payment%20Advice%20Report%202.xml?dl=0)
[RTF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai2vkzt6pik428r/ROHDCCCPAR-05272016-1.rtf?dl=0)

Comment: Could you upload the RTF file ? The one uploaded only has a picture of the BIP code.

Comment: It is not a picture. You have to download it bu clicking on the Download button from upper right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what I got: [image]

I had to re-arrange the end of the 'for' tags, then make the second row conditionally visible , with this condition

```
<?if:position()!=last()?>
```

Modified RTF file is [here](https://transfer.sh/eNVjV/ROHDCCCPAR-05272016-1.rtf).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put an `if` condition on the smaller row which you don't want to appear at the end. Check if the position != the count of records, then display the row.